# ListBox in C# doesn't show up

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I already have a ListBox in my Code and now I added a new one:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="Diaryresult"
                             Foreground="Black"
                             Margin="19,0,0,8">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Binding {name}"
                                               FontSize="24" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

I am populating this list with following code:

```
   XElement diary = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                IEnumerable<XElement> diaryelements = diary.Elements("diaryelement");

                List<Produkt> diaryprodukte = new List<Produkt>();

                foreach (XElement diaryelement in diaryelements)
                {
                    Produkt p = new Produkt();
                    p.name = diaryelement.Element("diaryshortitem").Element("description").Element("name").Value;
                    p.shortfacts = diaryelement.Element("diaryshortitem").Element("data").Element("kj").Value + " KJ - "
                            + diaryelement.Element("diaryshortitem").Element("data").Element("kcal").Value + "kcal";
                    diary.Add(p);

                    Debug.WriteLine("Added "+p.name);
                }
                Diaryresult.ItemsSource = diaryprodukte;


                Diaryresult.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

But, it doesn't show up. Does anyone see the trick?

Comment: I think this is XAML, not WebForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding tag isn't correct. "Binding {Name}" doesn't means anything for XAML. {Binding Name} means to [databind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) the property Name of your context which is what you're trying to do.

Replace:

```
<TextBlock Text="Binding {name}" FontSize="24" />
```

With:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="24" />
```

Also you need to add the element to the list:

```
dairyprodukt.Add(p);
```

And, remember to call your [NotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)() once done in order to notify the UI Thread of the changes. I mean, you're using `Diaryresult.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;` is this your way to notify your UI, are you using MVVM or CodeBehind?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are adding your Produkt to dairyprodukte. dairyprodukte is still an empty list when you bind it.

try

```
foreach (XElement diaryelement in diaryelements)
            {
                Produkt p = new Produkt();
                p.name = diaryelement.Element("diaryshortitem").Element("description").Element("name").Value;
                p.shortfacts = diaryelement.Element("diaryshortitem").Element("data").Element("kj").Value + " KJ - "
                        + diaryelement.Element("diaryshortitem").Element("data").Element("kcal").Value + "kcal";
                diary.Add(p);

                Debug.WriteLine("Added "+p.name);
                diaryprodukte.Add(p);
            }
```